# Question about modulo of prime numbers (or prime factorization (I guess))

Tags: discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

I would like to prove the following:

Let $p$ and $q$ different prime numbers and let $a$ be an integer such that $a < p$ and $a < q$.

I want to prove that 
$$pq \; | \; a^{pq} - a^p - a^q + a$$

i.e. I would like to prove:
$$ \frac{a^{pq} - a^p - a^q + a}{pq} \in \mathbb{Z}$$.

Can any body help me to prove this?

Comment: Note: the requirement that $a<p,q$ is extraneous.

Comment: So, you mean that without that restriction, this problem is solvable?
If you have any kind of hint, please tell me.

Comment: @StellaBiderman it implies that $\gcd(a,p) = \gcd(a,q) = 1$ which is enough to get the result.

Comment: Theorem: If $p$ is prime then $a^p\equiv a \pmod p$ for every integer $a.$ So modulo $p$ we have $a^{pq}-a^p-a^q+a\equiv$ $ (a^p)^q-a^p-a^q+a\equiv$ $ a^q-a^p-a^q+a\equiv$ $ -a^p+a\equiv 0.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet might be worth mentioning that this is Fermat's Little Theorem.

Comment: @DarthGeek That’s not a necessary assumption though.

Comment: @ApplicableMath Yes, I mean that this is also true if you let $a=p$ or $a=q$ or any other integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *lil' Fermat*:

Since $p$ is prime, $a^p\equiv a\mod p$, so $a^{pq}-a^p-a^q+a\equiv a^q-a-a^q+a\equiv 0\mod p$

Similarly  $a^{pq}-a^p-a^q+a\equiv 0\mod q$.

So   $a^{pq}-a^p-a^q+a\equiv 0\mod pq$ by the *Chinese remainder theorem*.

Answer (score 4):

Show it for p divides the entity and similarly the same argument will hold for q. Now I think using fermats little theorem will help. $ a^{qp} - a^q - (a^p - a)$ will be divided by p.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is correct that this can be easily solved by Fermat’s Little Theorem. However, you also need a second lemma that went unstated so I’ll state and prove it.

*Definition:* Let $a,b,c\in\mathbb Z$ such that $a$ is prime. Then $a|bc\Rightarrow a|b$ or $a|c$.

> **Lemma:** Let $p,q\in\mathbb Z$ be distinct primes. Then for all $x\in\mathbb Z$
>
> $$p| x\land q|x\iff pq|x$$

*Proof:* The $\Leftarrow$ direction is trivial. For the $\Rightarrow$ direction, suppose that $x=kp=\ell q$. Since $q|kp$ and distinct primes don’t divide each other, by the definition of primality we have that $q|k$. Therefore $x=mpq\Rightarrow $pq|x$.